# Javascript: отключить Caps Lock

Tags: javascript

Юзер вводит в текстовое поле информацию. Нужно как-то проверить включен ли Caps Lock и если да, тогда отключать его. Можно ли это реализовать с помощью javascript?

Comment: вот в помощь : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17180/Detect-Caps-Lock-with-Javascript

Comment: почему бы просто не вводить значения всегда в нижнем регистре?

Comment: @ThisMan На сайт ежедневно заходят сотни пользователей и попробуйте каждому объяснить что нужно в текстовом поле писать в нижнем регистре

Comment: @aleks_sk, нет, вы не поняли, почему бы программно не приводить введенное значение к нижнему регистру?

Answer (score 1):

Можно проверять включен ли Caps Lock, к примеру с помощью [этой](http://code.stephenmorley.org/javascript/detecting-the-caps-lock-key/) библиотеки.

Если Вы хотите чтоб в поле вводили данные только в нижнем регистре, то есть вариант куда лучше и без использования JS, добавьте стиль на поле ввода:

```
text-transform: lowercase;
```

К примеру:

```
<input name="email" type="text" style="text-transform: lowercase;">
```

UPD: Если же нужно чтобы и в input значение было в нижнем регистре то самый простой вариант:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input', function() {
    if (CapsLock.isOn()){
        $(this).val($(this).val().toLowerCase());
    }
});
```

Можете вообще всё сразу переводить в нижний регистр, просто уберите проверку `CapsLock.isOn()`

Comment: с css вводится будет с учетом регистра. только показываться будет без.

Comment: Вариант с событием `keyup` не очень хороший, т.к. поскольку он перезаписывает значение `input`, то фокус постоянно будет смещаться на последний символ.

Comment: Возможно он и не хороший, но этот способ использует ВК к примеру, поэтому и посоветовал